# Java: Creating a program to find surface area and volume of a cylinder

Tags: java

I am trying to make a program with two methods which calculate and return the surface area and volume of a cylinder.

When i run the program the system outputs 0.00 for both and i'm unsure of what i'm doing wrong.

Here is my code:

```
public class Circle {
public static int height; 
public static int radius; 
public static double pi = 3.14; 

public Circle(int height, int radius) { 
    height = 10; 
    radius = 5; 
}


public static double getSurfaceArea() {
    int radiusSquared = radius * radius; 
    double surfaceArea = 2 * pi * radius * height + 2 * pi * radiusSquared; 
    return surfaceArea; 
}

public static double getVolume() { 
    int radiusSquared = radius * radius; 
    double volume = pi * radiusSquared * height; 
    return volume; 
}


public static void main(String[] args) { 
    System.out.println("The volume of the soda can is: " + getVolume() + "."); 
    System.out.println("The surface area of the soda is: " + getSurfaceArea() + "."); 
}
```

}

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The variables are initialized to their default value, i.e 0. But there is a more fundamental problem here. It seems that you made these variables static (probably because of the compile errors you had when trying to call it from the main method). You need to remove the static modifiers in the Circle class and, in the main method, create a new instance of Circle and then call the `getVolume()` and `getSurfaceArea()` on this instance. See also https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classes.html

Comment: You are confusing static and instance variables, methods.

Comment: You are using paramters for your circle constructur, but overwrite them with constant values -> this renders the parameters useless.

Answer (score 1):

You have to add this line of code to your main:

```
Circle c = new Circle(10,5);
```

so it would be like so:

```
public static void main(String[] args) { 
    Circle c = new Circle(10,5);
    System.out.println("The volume of the soda can is: " + c.getVolume() + "."); 
    System.out.println("The surface area of the soda is: " + c.getSurfaceArea() + "."); 
}
```

and change your circle constructor method to this:

```
public Circle(int height, int radius) {
this.height = height;
this.radius = radius;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! Realized what I have done wrong now, thanks

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is what you are looking for:

```
public class Circle {
public static int height; 
public static int radius; 
public static double pi = 3.14; 

public Circle(int height, int radius) { 
    this.height = height; 
    this.radius = radius; 
}


public static double getSurfaceArea() {
    int radiusSquared = radius * radius; 
    double surfaceArea = 2 * pi * radius * height + 2 * pi * radiusSquared; 
    return surfaceArea; 
}

public static double getVolume() { 
    int radiusSquared = radius * radius; 
    double volume = pi * radiusSquared * height; 
    return volume; 
}


public static void main(String[] args) { 
Circle circle = new Circle(10,5);
    System.out.println("The volume of the soda can is: " + circle.getVolume() + "."); 
    System.out.println("The surface area of the soda is: " + cirlce.getSurfaceArea() + "."); 
}
}
```